# What is the Common Good According to Hobbes?

Tags: good-and-evil, social-contract, state, hobbes, rousseau

Two key arguments of Hobbes' in his *Leviathan* seem to be the ideas of "state of nature" and "social contract."

If I am correct in my interpretation, it seems that once a commonwealth is formed by a social contract, the political community (i.e., state) then proceeds to issue certain commands or prohibitions for the "common good."

How did Hobbes interpret the *common good?* Also, did Rousseau differ from Hobbes in his thoughts on the common good?

Comment: The common good according to Hobbes is the satisfaction of desires. https://www.jstor.org/stable/43155041 Rousseau is very similar but more developed, talks very directly about the fact that different individuals' desires may oppose and cancel out but the common good is the sum result of taking each individuals desires into account. Rousseau is cited a bunch here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/common-good/

Comment: @BrianZ Many thanks for the links. Unfortunately, I don't have a JSTOR account. Would you know of another way of accessing the article you cite?

Comment: @BrianZ Would the "common good" be some sort of collective desires?

Comment: "Collective desires" sort of, but Hobbes and Rousseau are both pretty individualistic so "collective" might give the wrong impression.

Comment: The common good shouldn't have helpful info be paywalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *The common good = salus publica = common welfare* is the
   superior principle, the souverain has to follow in his political
   decision, see Chapter 30 of Leviathan following the keyword [Salus
   populi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salus_populi_suprema_lex_esto).

   The concept has already been used by Cicero.

   Unfortunately I do not know from Hobbes’ writing a precise
   definition of the content.  I assume that justice is part of Hobbes
   understanding of salus publica. But I do not know to which degree
   Hobbes refers to Aristotle’s concept of justice as a virtue. I am a bit
   sceptical that to foucs on “desires” hits the main point, as @BrianZ comments.
2. There are differences between Hobbes and Rousseau in their
   anthropologies. If you can read German see [Thomas Hobbes und
   Jean-Jacques Rousseau](https://www.gsi.uni-muenchen.de/lehreinheiten/ls_pt1/lehre/2009/ue_pt/ue_pt5/index.html) . But I do not know if their
   anthropological differences are relevant for their interpretation of
   the concept of the common good.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort und für den hilfreichen Link.

Comment: @DDS I can send you Bertram's paper, referred to by BrianZ, on request.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness; however, I have discovered that the college I live near has access to the Southwestern Journal of Philosophy---so, I should be able to get the article there. Besides, I have some books I want to return to them this week. Thanks again.